# SQL query times out although all records have been read

Tags: select, sql-server-2005-express

For several years I've been using a C# application that is using a SQL Server 2005 Express database with about 250 tables. What could cause suddenly (never happened before) a simple `SELECT *` query from a single table to read all records from the table, but not reaching "Query executed successfully"; instead the query hangs, and stops only after timeout is reached.

Comment: Are you sure it is returning ALL rows.  I have seen in testing where a Transaction is Open and a row is inserted into a table.  Another connection is opened and selects from the table.  That select will return rows but no all of them until the other Transaction is committed or rolled back.

Comment: Does select * from table WITH (NOLOCK) hang?